# For Prisma Client join queries is it possible to move deeply nested fields to top level of result?

Tags: javascript, json, prisma

Does Prisma have the ability to move nested fields from another table join to the top level of the result, like a flattened view? I want to put the result JSON into a frontend table without digging through nested objects and building another object.

For example I want to replicate this behavior where I can pick and choose the columns from different tables (columns from User, and School). Currently I use a raw query with a similar SQL, however I wonder if it's possible with using only the Prisma API:

```
SELECT 
u.id
, u.email
, s.school_name
FROM "User" AS u
JOIN "UserSchool" AS us ON us.user_id = u.id
JOIN "School" AS s ON s.id = us.school_id
```

```
id | email              | school_name
123| student1@email.com | mount high

I want JSON that looks like this:
{
        "id": "1",
        "email": "student1@email.com",
        "school_name": "mount high",
}
```

If I did this in Prisma, I would need to go into several levels of nested objects to get the same column name on another table for e.g. `user[user_school][schoo][school_name]`. This requires extra work to loop through all my results, extract from the nested object, and build another object. This example isn't too bad, but I have more joins and deeply nested objects for my actual problem (lots of association/lookup tables). I've experimented with the `select` and `include` for my joins, but they are structured with the nested JSON.

```
users = await prisma.user.findMany({
        include: {
          user_school: {
            include: {
              school: true,
            },
          },
        },
```

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "email": "student1@email.com",
        "user_school": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": "1",
                "school_id": "1",
                "school": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "school_name": "mountain high",
                }
            }
        ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to flatten out the results as of now.

The only way to achieve this would be by using [rawQuery](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) as you mentioned.

However, there is an existing [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9719) which discusses Flattening out the results by providing an option of `flatten:true`. If you could mention your use case there and add a comment it would help Prisma's Product and engineering team in prioritising it.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know! I'll go ahead and do that.